# Why do ships appear to stretch when they jump to warp?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, warp

In the *TNG* opening credits the *Enterprise-D* stretches for a second when jumping to warp then returns to normal.  I've got a short video with a scene where it is shown:

I always thought it was simply because the ship warped space around the ship, so from our viewing perspective the ship appeared to stretch, but it really hadn't.  When you watch this scene closely, though, the *Enterprise* stretches, *then un-stretches to normal whilst still at warp*.

**What is the *in-universe* reason for this 'stretching' effect?**

Comment: appereantly we've got some kind of a joker who is downvoting EVERYTHING

Comment: @Petersaber I've  noticed with my last couple of questions have all been downvoted without much explanation provided - very annoying indeed!

Comment: @Petersaber : Indeed, it seems that way.  I think this person, whoever it is, has more than one account, because sometimes two lone downvotes come in almost simultaneously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Star Trek* warp drive is similar to the Alcubierre drive, a theoretical faster-than-light drive proposed by physicist Miguel Alcubierre in 1994.

From the Wikipedia [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) on the Alcubierre drive:

> The Star Trek television series used the term "warp drive" to describe their method of faster-than-light travel. Neither the Alcubierre theory, nor anything similar, existed when the series was conceived, but Alcubierre stated in an email to William Shatner that his theory was directly inspired by the term used in the show, and references it in his 1994 paper.

In particular, the Alcubierre drive uses a "warp bubble", and is the best model we currently have for understanding *Star Trek*'s warp drive at a mathematical / general relativistic level.  The idea has been revisited more recently by other theoretical physicists, as also stated in the article above:

> In 2012, physicist Harold White and collaborators announced that modifying the geometry of exotic matter could reduce the mass–energy requirements for a macroscopic space ship from the equivalent of the planet Jupiter to that of the Voyager 1 spacecraft (~700 kg) or less, and stated their intent to perform small-scale experiments in constructing warp fields. White proposed changing the shape of the warp bubble from a sphere to a torus. Furthermore, if the intensity of the space warp can be oscillated over time, the energy required is reduced even more. According to White, a modified Michelson–Morley interferometer could test the idea: ***one of the legs of the interferometer would appear to be a slightly different length when the test devices were energized.***

The implication is that an object moving in a warp bubble should appear to have a length differential (relative to its usual appearance) when viewed by an observer at rest — such as ourselves when we watch a starship go to warp.

(*Note* : I checked the *Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual* before investigating the Alcubierre model.)

Comment: Very interesting, especially considering that the proposed drive existed before *TNG* did! +1

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.   See my answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : It does.  An object moving in an Alcubierre warp bubble should have a length differential when viewed by an observer at rest (such as ourselves, when we watch the Enterprise go to warp).

Comment: @Praxis:  A small length differential doesn't explain long trails.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : It's not clear that the differential would be small for a starship...but let me say that I do like your answer too...see further comment below it. :-)

Comment: Alcubierre didn't publish his paper until 1994, so even if the writers wanted to use an idea like this it would have to be a retcon, rather than something the original effects designer was thinking of. And I don't think there's anything in any post-1994 episodes to suggest they did in fact decide to use this kind of explanation. Also, a lot of descriptions of warp (revolving around the concept of "subspace") in the shows and the technical manual don't match up very well with the Alcubierre drive. I think the most plausible in-universe answer is that it has to do with yet-unknown warp physics.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I did say in the first line of my answer, *"...proposed by physicist Miguel Alcubierre in 1994."*  I also agree that there is no evidence to suggest that writers had it in mind in the post-1994 material.  I only believe that this is the best model we currently have for understanding the Star Trek warp drive, and even in this somewhat "bad" model for the warp drive (I hesitate to use "bad" because I actually know Miguel Alcubierre!), there is evidence that there would be a length differential....

Comment: @Hypnosifl: But since yet-unknown physics is clearly responsible for the warp drive, I would concur with you that the reason for the differential is also in such physics.  (Since we don't know the content of such theories, I can only provide a reference point from known theories.)

Comment: "White proposed changing the shape of the warp bubble from a sphere to a torus." Interestingly, this is also what happens to the warp field when the Traveler works on it in ST:TNG's "Where No One Has Gone Before"

Comment: No, an Alcubierre Drive would create gravitational lensing affecting how things appear from behind the craft, but not the ship itself.

Answer (score 7):

In the first season episode "The Battle", [the Picard Maneuver](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Picard_Maneuver) is described.   The entire point of this maneuver is to jump to high warp so that the ship appears to be in two places at once.   This is because if you travel faster than light, then your light from the two positions can arrive at an observer at the same time.   In some ways, this is like a [sonic boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_boom), where the sound arrives at an observer at the same time or reinforces itself from multiple points of or a smeared out area of issue.   The stretch you're seeing makes sense as the artifact of light from a ship all along that trail arriving at you at the same time.

Below are three captures during the process of the Picard Maneuver showing the trails ***in universe***

[image: Before warp]
[image: During warp]
[image: After warp]

(Out of universe:  If you think about it, this should only happen if the ship is coming towards you.   Chalk the rest up to artistic license.)

Comment: This is a nice, simple explanation.  It doesn't explain why some starships *don't* exhibit the stretching when they go to warp (e.g the original Enterprise, or the Enterprise-E in the later *TNG* films), whereas variances in the shape of the warp field *could* explain why the effect might not be seen in some ships (e.g. White's spherical vs. toroidal warp bubbles). Regardless, I have +1'ed your answer --- nice work, PopMachine. :-)

Comment: @Praxis:   Not true--   The geometry or the direction of warp vs. the location of the observer could create many different effects or lack of.

Comment: In-universe, we see any particular vessel (original Enterprise, Enterprise-D, etc.) from many different orientations and the effect seems fairly constant for a particular vessel.  But what you say is fair, nonetheless.

Comment: Actually, I think the Picard Maneuver is stupid for two reasons.   (1) Ships clearly have faster-than-light sensors and (2) Anyone with half a brain would know that if you see two images of the same ship and the trails between them, then the closer image and the one with its tail pointed to the other's nose is the newer one.   Don't fire on the old one.  Duh!  This is high-school warp mechanics stuff.

Comment: I completely agree with you.  Nice use of screenshots, by the way.  :-)

Comment: If it's close enough to see, we are talking seconds, fractions even. The response time makes it hard to counter.

Comment: @Praxis:   Stolen from the Picard Maneuver page linked in the answer.

Comment: @cde:   If it just response time, then why do they make a point of talking about how the two images confused the Ferengi and they didn't know which to fire at.

Comment: Because a fight is decided in seconds. Also, the entire maneuver takes 2 seconds in screen time. At which point data triggers the tractor beam. The Picard maneuver is a surprise hail mary. If you are familiar with and expect it, it's not at all useful. The Ferengi had no clue that it could be done and suddenly had to valid to sensors ship appear.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is shaky ground on my part because the only thing I know about warp drive I read back before TNG and I don't recall where I read it.  But as I understand, the warp effect actually makes the distances between things shorter.  It has something to do with wormholes, as evidenced in the first TOS film when something went wrong and the ship nearly fell into a wormhole accidentally created by an out of balance engine.

The ship enters warp space, where everything is closer together.  The stretching effect shows the visual effect from the pov of an observer watching as the ship enters this "condensed universe" while in motion.  The ship appears to stretch because of the difference between the fore and aft of the ship during transition into warp space.  Once the ship has finished entering warp, those differences disappear and the ship appears normal again, but seems to be moving very fast.

Think of it as something like watching a stick enter a glass of water.  The stick seems to bend and actually looks slightly bigger because of the water's refractory properties, but once it's fully emerged it just looks like an ordinary stick again, just larger.

The problem with bringing the speed of light into it is that there should be a color shift in that case.  Picard's account of one ship becoming two can't be right because an observer would notice a color difference.  Therefore I suggest that the Captain was speaking in layman's terms, or that he himself understood the mechanics involved too poorly to give a proper accounting of them.

As to why no stretching effect on older model ships, I suggest that the effect was there but not as noticeable because warp fields were less powerful and ships entered warp less smoothly.

Unless of course I understood wrongly, in which case forget about all of the above.

Comment: I like the answer about how from an outer perspective, the ship appears to stretch. It makes sense. I have also enjoyed the 'light streaks' warp effect from the Kirk era - the first 6 Star Trek movies.
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vOLi2.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vOLi2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Actually as I understand it this is backwards. The ship should contract and there should be a general light lensing effect around the bubble.